# C++ template add/enable constructor based on template argument

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Is it possible in the following scenario to define dedicated constructors for certain specializations of a template:

```
template<typename T, size_t D>
class vector {
  T values[D];
public:
  vector();
};
```

Constructors I want to add dependent on the D-argument:

```
template<typename T>
vector<T, 2>::vector(T t1, T t2) { ... }

template<typename T>
vector<T, 3>::vector(T t1, T t2, T t3) { ... }

template<typename T>
vector<T, 4>::vector(T t1, T t2, T t3, T t4) { ... }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template<bool B>
using EnableIfB = typename std::enable_if<B, int>::type;

template<typename T, size_t D>
class vector {
  T values[D];
public:
  template<size_t D1 = D, EnableIfB<D1 == 2> = 0>
  vector(T t1, T t2) { ... }

  template<size_t D1 = D, EnableIfB<D1 == 3> = 0>
  vector(T t1, T t2, T t3) { ... }

  template<size_t D1 = D, EnableIfB<D1 == 4> = 0>
  vector(T t1, T t2, T t3, T t4) { ... }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 because I didn't know using statements could be templated, very handy!

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but my compiler complains that I can't provide default parameters on the constructor template?!

Comment: @MFH your compiler is outdated. You cannot use my solution then.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: is there a solution that would work on VC10?

Comment: If you're using an older compiler, you can make the enable_if< ... >::type a default parameter you your constructor instead of a default template argument. It's uglier but it works.

Comment: @bstamour that still leaves the `= D` default argument

Comment: Ah yes my bad. I forgot about that little guy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider defining all of the constructors for the primary template `vector<T, D>`, then `static_assert` in each constructor to ensure the arity matches.  For example:

```
vector(T t0, T t1)
{
    static_assert(D == 2, "Eeeeeeeekkkkk!  Wrong constructor!");
}
```